# InvalidCastException in Xamarin iOS

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, linq-to-twitter

I'm receiving an `InvalidCastException` when running my code in Xamarin iOS. This doesn't happen for .NET or Android - only for iOS.  Here's the exception details:

> at
>   Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.EqualInstruction+EqualInt64.DoCalculate
>   (System.Object l, System.Object r) [0x00000] in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/3426/6c3fee4d/source/xamarin-macios/_ios-build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/mcs/class/dlr/Runtime/Microsoft.Dynamic/Interpreter/Instructions/EqualInstruction.cs:84
>   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.ComparisonInstruction.Calculate
>   (System.Object l, System.Object r) [0x00015] in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/3426/6c3fee4d/source/xamarin-macios/_ios-build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/mcs/class/dlr/Runtime/Microsoft.Dynamic/Interpreter/Instructions/ComparisonInstruction.cs:44
>   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.ArithmeticInstruction.Run
>   (Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.InterpretedFrame frame) [0x00020] in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/3426/6c3fee4d/source/xamarin-macios/_ios-build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/mcs/class/dlr/Runtime/Microsoft.Dynamic/Interpreter/Instructions/ArithmeticInstruction.cs:45
>   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.Interpreter.Run
>   (Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.InterpretedFrame frame) [0x0001b] in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/3426/6c3fee4d/source/xamarin-macios/_ios-build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/mcs/class/dlr/Runtime/Microsoft.Dynamic/Interpreter/Interpreter.cs:126
>
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---   at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw ()
>   [0x0000c] in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/3426/6c3fee4d/source/xamarin-macios/_ios-build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:143
>   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess
>   (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00047] in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/3426/6c3fee4d/source/xamarin-macios/_ios-build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:187
>   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification
>   (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0002e] in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/3426/6c3fee4d/source/xamarin-macios/_ios-build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:156
>   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd
>   (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0000b] in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/3426/6c3fee4d/source/xamarin-macios/_ios-build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:128
>   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1[TResult].GetResult ()
>   [0x00000] in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/3426/6c3fee4d/source/xamarin-macios/_ios-build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:357
>   at
>   XamarinFormsPortable.Models.TweetingViewModel+d__4.MoveNext
>   () [0x00328] in
>   C:\Projects\LinqToTwitter\Samples\Xamarin4\XamarinFormsPortable\XamarinFormsPortable\XamarinFormsPortable\Models\TweetingViewModel.cs:54

The code that causes the problem is a LINQ to Twitter query:

```
            var ctx = new TwitterContext(auth);
            ulong InitialTweetId = 1;
            int MaximumTweetsToRetrieve = 20;

            var tweetsQuery = from tweet in ctx.Status
                              where tweet.Type == StatusType.User &&
                              tweet.ScreenName == "reinoso_alvaro" &&
                              tweet.Text.Contains("#buenosdias") &&
                              tweet.IncludeRetweets == false &&
                              tweet.TrimUser == true &&
                              tweet.ExcludeReplies == true &&
                              tweet.SinceID == InitialTweetId &&
                              tweet.Count == MaximumTweetsToRetrieve
                              select tweet;
            var tweetList = await tweetsQuery.ToListAsync();
```

The condition that causes the problem is `SinceID`, which is `ulong`. However, you can see from the stack trace that the last method is `EqualInt64`, which is `long`. I looked for every place where I worked with `SinceID` and they are all `ulong`. The exception occurs on the last line: `awaiting tweetsQuery.ToListAsync()`

The implementation of `ToListAsync` is:

```
    public static async Task<List<T>> ToListAsync<T>(this IQueryable<T> query)
    {
        var provider = query.Provider as TwitterQueryProvider;

        IEnumerable<T> results = (IEnumerable<T>)await provider.ExecuteAsync<IEnumerable<T>>(query.Expression).ConfigureAwait(false);

        return results.ToList();
    }
```

`ExecuteAsync` runs and returns results. Then the exception occurs when materializing via `results.ToList()`.

This is only happening on iOS.

Comment: and without `tweet.SinceID == InitialTweetId` it's working?

Comment: @Sven-MichaelStübe Without SinceID, It doesn't throw an exception, but logically it won't work because it's a necessary for paging.

Answer (score 0):

A possible workaround is to cast the Status.SinceID property in the expression:

```
[...]
&& (long)tweet.SinceID == sinceStatusId // sinceStatusId is a long
[...]
```

Interesting point, Mono's Interpreter object comparison instructions for unsigned integers are assigned instances of their signed counterparts (https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/mono-4.8.0-branch/mcs/class/dlr/Runtime/Microsoft.Dynamic/Interpreter/Instructions/EqualInstruction.cs , line 155 to 157):

```
case TypeCode.UInt16: return _UInt16 ?? (_UInt16 = new EqualInt16());
case TypeCode.UInt32: return _UInt32 ?? (_UInt32 = new EqualInt32());
case TypeCode.UInt64: return _UInt64 ?? (_UInt64 = new EqualInt64());
```

Not sure if this is intentional or not.

Comment: While the cast to long might work today, SinceID is intentionally ulong to handle the potential for the size to grow. Also, signed isn't semantically correct in this scenario. That said, this would be a temporary work-around.